# How to go to custom command implementation in cypress (vscode)

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress, shortcut

I'm using `custom commands` in Cypress and it's working fine when I run my tests directly. The problem is how do I go to the implementation from `cy.login()`. `CTRL + left` click doesn't perform any action.

My `command.js` file looks like below:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (email,password) =>{
    login.email().type(email);
    login.password().type(password);
});
```

My `login.js` file looks like below:

```
When("I type in email and password", function(){
    cy.login('test','testt`)
});
```

The `index.js` file as below:

```
import './commands'
```

If I click `Ctrl + left` click on `cy.login()` doesn't take me to the `command.js` file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using TypeScript in Cypress to get that functionality. It is not built into JavaScript in Cypress.

Answer (score 1):

You can create cypress/support/index.d.ts file

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject> {
    /**
     * Login description
     */
    login(email:string,password:string): Chainable<any>

}
}
```

In spec file

> login.js

add below lines

```
   ///  <reference types="cypress" /> 
   ///  <reference path="../support/index.d.ts" />
```

You can refer https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-todomvc#cypress-intellisense